# Content Provider for Settings/Call Settings/Internet Call Settings/Accounts

Tags: android, settings, android-contentprovider, sip

I'm new to Android development and the last piece of real code I touched was over 10 years ago.

I went thru the google documentation on the settings content provider, but it seems only some of the settings are exposed. I'm struggling to find a way to get access to the Call Settings, in particular I want to get the list of SIP accounts from Settings/Call Settings/Internet Call Settings/Accounts.

I'm hoping to monitor the registration status of these accounts from my app.